# AngularJS - ControllerAs ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs, controlleras

I'm struggling with getting no response from an ng-click on a project I'm working on. To isolate the problem, I've created a simple plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/N4tDDcP5wmeKC5keSHAj?p=preview

There are no error messages on page load, no error message on click, and no alert() box displayed on click. Nothing happens at all.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-click-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('testController', function() {

      var vm = this;
      vm.test = test;

      function test() {
        alert("test");
      }

    });



  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="testController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.test()">
      Test with controllerAs
    </button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed **ng-app** on body, see below:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.test()">
    Test
  </button>
  <span>
</span>
</body>
```

See updated plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kBPOEpTvZBnNZJ1PchL2?p=info

Comment: Oh god, what an idiot I am. Thanks Vitalia. This was actually a cut-down version of a complex app I'm working on, that has the same issue. I'll see if the app has the same problem. I think this is the only time I'm using ng-click, so it could be the same issue. Thanks again. I'll confirm back once I've checked the main app.

Comment: Just checked by source code - I did have the ng-app, but it was assigned to the <html> element, not the <body> element. I modified your plunkr to assign the ng-app to the <html> and it failed as well.

Comment: Aaah, my mistake it is working. However, the template I'm using for the core HTML page also has an ng-click on the HTML element. I'm guess that causing some conflict.

Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Glad you're figured it out! Happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks Vitali. It turns out it's something to do with the angular datatables module I'm using (or the underlying jquery datables that sit behing the angular module). It's going to be fun working out the issue - I think I'll find another solution :-)